# How can I export db.collection(CollectionName)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im looking for a way to exports my `db.collection(collectionName)` as an object that I can use it later. I'm exporting functions in `DBConfig.js`and it's looks like this :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const DB_Name = process.env.DB_NAME


var getCollectionFn = (CollectionName,callback)=>{


    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db(DB_Name);
      callback(dbo.collection(CollectionName) )

    });
}

exports.products = ()=>{
    getCollectionFn("products", data=>{ return data})
}
```

Also in other file `products.js` I'm using this function like this :

```
const mongoDbCollection = require('../config/DBConfig');
const products = mongoDbCollection.products;

module.exports = productsControllers = {
  getAllProducts: () => {
        products.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
                return result;
          });

    }
}
```

but I got an err and it says `TypeError: products.find is not a function`. So I'm not much familiar with this. can U help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why you are having the error:**

You are having this error because, in `DBConfig.js`, you exported `products` as a function:

```
exports.products = ()=>{
    getCollectionFn("products", data=>{ return data})
}
```

However, in `product.js` where you imported `products`, you tried using it as an *object*, calling `.find()` method on it:

```
// ...other controller codes
products.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
      return result;
});
// ...other controller codes
```

This won't work because you don't have a `.find()` method on the `products` function and this is why you are getting the TypeError: `TypeError: products.find is not a function`.

**The Fix:**

To get the `products` function working the way I believe you want it to, you need to update both the way it was exported and the way it's being used. The exporting in `DBConfig.js` should be something like this:

```
// The update to this functions is simply adding a way 
// to close the opened MongoDB connection
var getCollectionFn = (CollectionName,callback)=>{
  var client =  new MongoClient(url);
  // The done function simply closes the mongoDB connection
  const done = () => {
    client.close();
  }
  client.connect(function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db(DB_Name);
    // Pass the done function to the call back
    callback(dbo.collection(CollectionName), done)
  });
}

exports.products = (callBack) => {
  // Notice the use of a callBack as opposed to what was there before
  getCollectionFn("products", callBack);
}
```

And the usage in the product controller should be something like this:

```
module.exports = productsControllers = {
    getAllProducts: (callback) => {
      // Note that the actual query is in a callback passed to the
      // products function as argument
      products((collection, done) => {
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          callback(result);
          // It's important to call the done method to avoid too many 
          // open connections
          done();
        });
      })
  }
}
```

You should note that unlike before, the `getAllProducts` controller won't be returning the list of products from the db, instead, you would need to pass a callback from whoever is making use of the `getAllProducts` controller to consume the result of the db query.

I feel this is gradually turning into a callback hell, you can save your self from that by using promises. The MongoDB connection and query methods can return promises for asynchronous operation.